# Javadoc generation failed : ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.javadoc.AnnotationTypeDoc

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm getting the following error when I do

```
mvn clean deploy -DperformRelease=true
```

> [ERROR] Exit code: 1 -   .java:3: package javax.inject does not
>   exist
>  [ERROR] import javax.inject.Named;
>  [ERROR] ^
>  [ERROR]
>   TransactionServiceExternalImpl.java:5: cannot  find symbol
>   [ERROR] symbol: class Named
>  [ERROR]
>   @Named("transactionServiceExternal")
>  [ERROR] ^
>  [ERROR]
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl
>   cannot be cast to com.sun.javadoc.AnnotationTypeDoc

The POM is this...

```
<groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>ts-impl/artifactId>
<version>2.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There is only one class...

```
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("transactionServiceExternal")
public class TransactionServiceExternalImpl 
{
}
```

I get the error with

- jdk1.5.0_22
- jdk1.6.0_29
- jdk1.6.0_43
- jdk1.6.0_43_32bit

But NOT with...

- jdk1.7.0_05

Anyone have any ideas?

Notes: Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 08:44:56+0000)

---

I now know that the reason is that the Maven Javadoc Plugin has changed from 2.9.1 to 2.10.
and this is the cause of the problem.

I can see this warning...

[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing.
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing.

By setting the following in my pom....

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
```

I can fix the version back to the last release.

I will raise a bug with the Maven Javadoc creators.

---

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC-407

---

On a side note: you can clone the SVN repo for version 2.9.1, update the pom to 2.10.1, do a mvn install to put it in you M2 folder. You should be up and working again, you just need to remove this tmp version when the real release comes out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Were having same problems in our projects. Theres a lot of people having this problem so should be a issue regarding maven-javadoc-plugin as [maven-javadoc-plugin breaks mvn release:perform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25983852/4066355) stated in first answer. The jira issue is http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC-408.

Temporal solutions:

- Execute build with `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true` option
- Add this property in pom.xml `<maven.javadoc.failOnError>false</maven.javadoc.failOnError>`
- Fix maven-javadoc-plugin version to 2.9.1 in your pluginManagement section like

> ```
> <pluginManagement>
>   <plugins>
>     <plugin>
>       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>       <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
>       <version>2.9.1</version>
>     </plugin>
>   </plugins>
> </pluginManagement>
> ```

I hope issue is fixed soon.

**Update**
According to Noremac in comments, if you are using *release plugin* and want to pass arguments to it, the right way to do it is -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true".

Ill keep the other way in my answer, because this is happening in any maven build that is using javadoc.

**Update 2**
Also TheConstructor in comments says that 2.10.1 version fix the problem. Im not able to check it out.

Comment: This is a good summary of options as of 2014-09-23. The only thing I could add is to watch/monitor and vote up http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC-408 .. or submit a patch :)

Comment: It's worth noting that `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true` doesn't help if you run `mvn release:perform`.

Comment: @MarcelStör this is incorrect. Following typical use of the release plugin, you need to pass arguments into it through something like -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true". This is what we have done here to get around the problem on our releases. http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html

Comment: @Noremac, ahh sigh...those forked executions...totally forgot about `-Darguments`. Thanks.

Comment: 2.10.1 is available and seems to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

We have the same problem and we temporarily solved this issue by explicitly specify Maven Javadoc Plugin version to 2.9.1

Answer (score 1):

From jira http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC-407:

> build classes (including 3rd-parties dependencies) are not on javadoc
>   classpath anymore

But if I add dependecies to maven-javadoc-plugin:

```
...
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.cayenne</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cayenne-server</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1B2</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
...
```

this not help.

Answer (score 1):

This somewhat worked for me, I had to add the plugin this way since we already had other plugins set for builds.  Note I removed our other plugins from the example below:

```
<build>     
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to parent pom:

```
<build>
...
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
...
<build>
```

solve problem

Answer (score 0):

Use following plugin to generate java docs.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
```